# WSO2 API Manager - load balancing with dynamic endpoints

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I've got an API that uses dynamic endpoints. Now I want it to also do load balancing. I know how to do that using  element, however when using dynamic endpoints in APIM you only manipulate the "To" header.

Below is the mediation sequence used to set the endpoint. Instead of addressing just a single endpoint in each  case, I'd like to be able to loadbalance between 2 servers.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="inSequence_clientEquipmentsAPI_1_2_STG" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <!-- check for healthcheck operation -->
    <filter xpath="get-property('To')='/etc/equipments/client/1.0/healthCheck'">
        <!-- if healthCheck, directs to healthCheck API (EI)-->
        <then>
            <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
            <header name="To" value="http://10.220.160.36:8290/healthCheck/clientEquipments"/>
        </then>
        <!-- else direct to regular clientEquipment API (EI)-->
        <else>
            <property name="newContext" expression="substring-after(get-property('To'),'/etc')"/>       
            <header name="To" expression="fn:concat('http://10.220.160.36:8290', $ctx:newContext)"/>
        </else>         
    </filter>
</sequence>
```